# How to decipher the year a sefer was published

Tags: jewish-books

I have come across many, generally older sefarim, without an explicit date given on the title page as to when the sefer was published. Instead they'll write that the sefer was published  in the year.... And quote a part of a pasuk.
For example :

נדפס פה לבוב בשנת שוש אשיש בד' לפ"ק

How does that tell me when the sefer was published?

Here's a photo of rhe title page:
[image]

Comment: It is customary to hint at the author's name or a verse that reflects the book's title. לפ"ק means "without thousands". "שוש אשיש" gives us 1217 which is too much. So I suppose בד' means 4th thousand (then לפ"ק is meaningless). That gives us a total of 5217 and year 1457CE. I don't think Lviv had a printing press back then. So it might be only אשיש which is 611 and year 1851CE. That sounds good but בד' is odd. Hm...

Comment: A photo of the text can help. Sometimes some letters are marked, e.g. with dots over them, to indicate that only those should be counted toward the sum.

Comment: @AlBerko אשיש is big letters in the original. That's the year. בד׳ is the continuation of the pasuk (ד for God)

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you, please edit my comment